# XSL help creating comma separated XML

Tags: xml

I'm stuck with something which is probably quite simple to resolve but don't have a clue.

My XML data is as follows :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="GetTicketCategories.xsl"?>
<ArrayOfCategory xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://test.com/test/">
  <Category>
    <Name>Benefits</Name>
    <Count>29</Count>
  </Category>
  <Category>
    <Name>Building Control</Name>
    <Count>4</Count>
  </Category>
 </ArrayOfCategory>
```

XSL file :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text"/> 
<xsl:template match="Category">

<xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
<xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="Count"/>
<xsl:text>, </xsl:text>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is :-

```
Benefits29Building Control4
```

There seems to be an issue with the top element where it doesn't like its formatting e.g. `<ArrayOfCategory xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://ctronix.com/smartticketservice/">`

I'm not in a position to change the xml but if I simplify the code it works as below :-

Changed XML :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="GetTicketCategories.xsl"?>
<ArrayOfCategory>
  <Category>
    <Name>Benefits</Name>
    <Count>29</Count>
  </Category>
  <Category>
    <Name>Building Control</Name>
    <Count>4</Count>
  </Category>
 </ArrayOfCategory>
```

XSL:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text"/> 
<xsl:template match="ArrayOfCategory/Category">

<xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
<xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="Count"/>
<xsl:text>, </xsl:text>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Correct Output:-

```
Benefits, 29, Building Control, 4,
```

So how do I get the required output using the existing XML file? I don't know how to use

```
<ArrayOfCategory xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://ctronix.com/smartticketservice/">
```

in the template match section.

I must confess I'm a complete beginner; any help would be very much appreciated.

Cheers

Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the first XSL template you posted does not match anything, so it defaults to outputting all text elements.

You need to change the template match - use `/ArrayOfCategory/Category`, which translates to "from the root of the xml, select all ArrayOfCategory/Category":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/> 

 <xsl:template match="/ArrayOfCategory/Category">

  <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
  <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="Count"/>
  <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: As simple as that! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference in XSL namespace used in XML. Check this XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:t="http://test.com/test/">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="t:ArrayOfCategory/t:Category">
    <xsl:value-of select="t:Name"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="t:Count"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="GetTicketCategories.xsl"?>
<ArrayOfCategory xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://test.com/test/">
  <Category>
    <Name>Benefits</Name>
    <Count>29</Count>
  </Category>
  <Category>
    <Name>Building Control</Name>
    <Count>4</Count>
  </Category>
</ArrayOfCategory>
```

Result:

```
Benefits,29,Building Control,4,
```